# HDRI Not Appearing In Final Render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, hdri

I am having issues with the final render and HDRIs. Whenever I render in the Cycles Engine, my HDRI disappears and replaces itself with the default background. [image]
Here is the image (note the lack of an HDRI)

Comment: Hello. please add more inffo about your node settiings, also some screenshots about that could help.

Comment: i would recommend download and install Easy HDRI add-on (no, unfortunately i don't get money from them for this advertising), but with just a few clicks you will get HDRI in your scene (and you can choose which one) and it works, in render too

Comment: If the given answer doesn't resolve your problem, screenshots of your nodes as Emir suggests might be helpful, like world node settings and the compositor nodes. Usually I just plug an HDRI into an Environment Texture in the World material and then it's there... no need for add-ons or complex node setups. So screenshots or the file would be good to investigate further...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this setup (which is essentially just a copy of what Easy HDRI just does for you automatically):

[image]

the good news: you made the node setup right.

the bad news: you have to change some parameters so that you can really see your background through your camera.

So first change to camera view and then zoom out. If you are zooming out far enough you will see the background image.

If you then "play" with the values (yours can differ) you can "push" your background image to the right place behind your camera.

my settings to "see" it were:

[image]

result: (after i changed your composite nodes to this:)

[image]

[image]

UPDATE ----

you can do it like this:

BUT...the more you glare (with fac) the less you will see the background.

[image]

Comment: I don't get what the last _Mix Shader_ node is supposed to do. I've used mixing backgrounds by camera ray before, too - but the _Is Camera Ray_ goes into a _Multiply_ with 0. This means, if it's not a camera ray, you'll get 0 * 0 = 0, the top background shader. If it is a camera ray, you'll get 1 * 0 = 0, the top shader again. The _Mix Shader_ and/or the bottom _Background Shader_ are useless. Or do I miss something?

Comment: i have no idea :D i just copied the setup which Easy HDRI gave me...and it worked for me. I never tried to understand it ;) i am sorry....

Comment: i just can guess...why it is that way. If you change manually some settings in the Add-on, maybe the addon then just changes the value in the multiplier... just a guess

Comment: I'm not familiar with the add-on, so this might well be the case. But since you give him this setup without using the add-on, it might not be obvious for everybody which node creates which result - so he might still be stuck with a problem.

Comment: i don't hope so, but if he is stuck, hopefully he will write it and i will try to help him.

Comment: I'm just thinking of people who might come here much later to find a solution.

Comment: I wrote it out myself because I'm totally unfamiliar with the plug-in. I got it right but unfortunately, the HDRI still isn't there. Why is that?

Comment: Ok, then please provide your blend file - I will check it

Comment: Actually, I have the file, but how do I upload it here?

Comment: Go to https://blend-exchange.com and follow instructions

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/b/Q2y7JGvD

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: I mean, it looks nice, but I'm missing that glow/glare that should emit from the neon. I'm using Cycles render btw

Comment: In Cycles there is no glow around light emitting materials, neither in 3D Viewport nor Render, that's just Eevee. In Cycles you have to composite it in afterwards.

Comment: @Micah: i updated my answer

Comment: Thank you, I completely understand. I made your answer the correct answer.

Comment: thank you! you are welcome